# replayer Timeout in the loop, please check the resolve tree data

Tags: javascript

I recorded some data using rrweb, but while playing it the rrweb player stucks for a while and throw the following warnings on the console

```
[replayer] Timeout in the loop, please check the resolve tree data: Array(1))
```

reproducible at this sandbox: https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-moptoy?file=index.html

Code is simple, but maybe the events have some issue.

```
<body>
    <div id="player"></div>
    <script>
        new rrwebPlayer({
            target: document.getElementById('player'),
            props: {
                events,
            },
        });
    </script>
</body>
```